# How do dryer sheets work?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge

For what I can understand they absorb the static electricity of clothes but how?

I'm confused because I thought that to neutralise a charge you would need to have the equal opposite charge and make contact with it. However Dryer sheets don't need any of that they just absorb it. how do they do that?

Comment: The are impregnated with fabric softener. The sheets themselves do nothing but release the fabric softener.

Answer (score -1):

Most dryer sheets are small pieces of non-woven synthetic fabrics coated with a solution of a quaternary ammonium salt or a silicone oil-based fabric softener. Some sheets are made of natural or cellulose fibers that can be recycled. The heat of the dryer softens the fabric softener allowing the coating to transfer to fabrics. It is this coating that makes clothes feel softer to the touch.

Dryer sheets reduce static electricity that forms in the dryer due to too many loose electrons giving clothing atoms a negative charge. The fabric softeners coating the dryer sheet fabric are cationic, or positively charged ions and equalize the electrons and ions to prevent static.

While a fragrance is not required to soften clothes or reduce static electricity, most manufacturers add a scent that some users enjoy.

Material gleaned from [this page](https://www.thespruce.com/are-dryer-sheets-bad-for-my-dryer-2145844) at The Spruce.

Other sources [here](https://home.howstuffworks.com/dryer-sheets.htm) and [here](http://sciencenetlinks.com/science-news/science-updates/dryer-sheets/).